# Filter Out Aggregates By Value

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create a wildcard search (yes in place of ngrams but it will be very low volume) that will resolve the values from a particular field, sorted by their frequency.

If I have a list of documents with the property `color`, with values "blue", "bluish" "red", "redish", etc., I want to search for values (not documents) that are like `"*blu*"`.

I can do this first by filtering documents by that wildcard, then using a terms agg to get the values and their usages.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "color": {
              "value": "*blu*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "profile_hits": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query would return results: `"blue", "bluish"`. Which is exactly what I want.

But there is an issue if the color field contains multiple values. Say there is a document with the color value as `["blue", "red"]`. Now when I search `"*blu*"` I will match on that document, which means my search for `"*blu*"` will return `"blue", "red"`.

I understand why this is happening. I'd like to know if there is a way I can further filter the aggs by the same wildcard, so it will not aggs on values that don't match `"*blu*"`. Or is this something I will need to do in the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `includes` regex filter work for you here? There is also the complimentary `excludes`.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_regular_expressions_2

```
"aggs": {
    "profile_hits": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color.keyword",
        "includes": "*blu*"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes it does! It's a regex so it needs to be `.*blue.*`